# Pagereference function:Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'return' at line 20 column 0

Tags: pagereference

I am new to SF apex programming,

Can any one help me out of this error and suggest me on the code  written.

Thanks for your help,

```
public class c6{

string keyword;
List<Account> acts;

public string getkeyword(){
return keyword;
}

public List<Account> getacts(){
return acts;
}

public void setkeyword(String s){
keyword = s;
}

public PageReference search(){
acts = (List<Account>)[FIND: keyword Returning Account(Name, Type, Industry, Phone, Fax)]
return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semi-colon (;) after the previous line. Even inline queries need to end with a semi-colon:

```
acts = (List<Account>)[FIND: keyword Returning Account(Name, Type, Industry, Phone, Fax)];
return null;
```

Comment: public class c6{

string keyword;
List<Account> acts;

public string getkeyword(){
return keyword;
}

public List<Account> getacts(){
return acts;
}

public void setkeyword(String S){
keyword = S;
}

public PageReference search(){
acts = (List<Account>)[FIND: keyword Returning Account(Name, Type, Industry, Phone, Fax)];
return null;
}

}

Comment: Hi Smith - Still I am getting the following error,

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Incompatible types since an instance of List<List<SObject>> is never an instance of List<Account> at line 19 column 8

Comment: @Jay You'll need to get the first list of lists, like this: `[FIND ... ][0]`. Even if there's only one returned object list, it's still a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

### VF Page

Visualforce Source Page coding:

```
< apex:page controller="cl3">


    <apex:form >


        <apex:pageBlock title="List of accounts">

            <apex:pageBlockSection >

                <apex:inputField value="{!Fields.Industry}"/>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                <a>Search </a>      <apex:inputText value="{!Keyword}" title="Search" size="25"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            </apex:pageBlockSection> 

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >

                <apex:commandButton value="Show All" Action="{!Showall}"     reRender="mylayout"/>

                <apex:commandButton value="Filter"   Action="{!ShowFilter}"  reRender="mylayout"/>                                                         

                <apex:commandButton value="Search"   Action="{!SearchText}"  reRender="mylayout"/>                

            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Displayrecords}" var="Record" id="mylayout">
                <apex:column value="{!Record.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Record.Type}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Record.Industry}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

### VF CLASS

```
public class cl3 {
    Account   acc1 = new Account();
    String    keywordText;

    List<Account> acc;
    List<List<Account>>  acc2;

    public Account getFields()
    {
          return acc1;
    }
    public void setKeyword(String s)
    {
        keywordText = s;
    }
    public String getKeyword()
    {

        return keywordText;
    }
    public PageReference SearchText()
    {
        List<List<sObject>> results;       
        results = [FIND :keywordText IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account (Name, Type, Industry)];
        sObject[] res = ((List<sObject>)results[0]);
        acc = res;  
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference Showall()
    {
        acc = [ select Name,Type,Industry from Account];

        return null;
    }

    public PageReference ShowFilter()

    {
        String v_val;

        if(acc1.Industry <> '') {

          v_val = acc1.Industry;    

          acc = [ select Name,Type,Industry from Account where Industry = :v_val ];

        }else
        {
            Showall();
        }


        return null;
    }

    public Account[] getDisplayrecords()
    {
        return acc;
    } 
}
```